# How do I serialize a Custom Collection in MongoDB.Bson?

Tags: c#, serialization, mongodb, bson

The documentation for the MongoDB.Bson.Serialization seems thin. I can't figure out how to get my custom collection into the MongoDB document correctly. I am using their [default c# Driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-Representation).

This is the class that I am trying to serialize, but when I look at the result after it is it serialized and then deserialized, the collection is empty. More specifically, it creates a new instance of the class, but the "_items" collection was coming out null. I found this unusual given that it was a private interior collection. This collection is a property of a much larger class, the other class properties are serializing correctly. I have been serializing this to XML using the built-in serializers and this worked fine. I figure it's probably something simple, but short of creating a custom serialization implementation I don't know what it is. Is there something I have to do to tell the serializer to treat this as a collection?

Since I am am brand new to the MongoDB, I haven't figured out how to dump large raw documents to inspect what the MongoDB document itself looks like. That's what I am working on now.

```
[XmlRootAttribute(ElementName = "Children", IsNullable = true)] 
public class ChildList : IList<SurveyItem>, ICollection<SurveyItem> 
{
    private SurveyItem _parent = null;
    public ChildList(SurveyItem iParent)
    {
        _parent = iParent;      
    }

    private List<SurveyItem> items = new List<SurveyItem>();        

    #region ICollection<SurveyItem> Members
    public void Add(SurveyItem item)
    {
        //wire up the child.
        item.Parent = _parent;
        items.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        items.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(SurveyItem item)
    {
        return items.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(SurveyItem[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        items.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return items.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool Remove(SurveyItem item)
    {
        item.Parent = null;
        return items.Remove(item);
    }
    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<SurveyItem> Members
    public IEnumerator<SurveyItem> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return items.GetEnumerator();
    }
    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (items as IEnumerable).GetEnumerator();
    }
    #endregion

    #region IList<SurveyItem> Members
    public int IndexOf(SurveyItem item)
    {
        return items.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, SurveyItem item)
    {
        item.Parent = _parent;
        items.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        items[index].Parent = null;
        items.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public SurveyItem this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return items[index];
        }
        set
        {
            value.Parent = _parent;
            items[index] = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public SurveyItem[] ToArray()
    {
        SurveyItem[] output = new SurveyItem[items.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            output[i] = items[i];
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give details of the much larger class? You can dump raw documents with the mongodump command. Here's how to use it with a single collection and a query: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-Example%3ADumpingaSingleCollectionwithaquery

Answer (score 2):

The serializer in the C# driver simply looks for and serializes the public read/write properties of a class. The serializer also has special cases for standard collection classes in .NET like Dictionary.

Your collection elements are stored in a private field called items. That's why they don't get serialized.

You could write a custom serializer for your class. You can either implement IBsonSerializable, or you could write an IBsonSerializer and register it with BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer.

One problem you will likely run into is circular references: your collection has a reference to a parent, which most likely in turn has a reference to the child. Circular references are hard to serialize.